# Are the input tags 'sanitised' in HTML?

Tags: html, validation, input, sanitization, html-sanitizing

Let's say a user adds some PHP code `<?php //code here ?>` into an input text tag (which they aren't supposed to in this case), would the opening and closing tags be converted into `&lt;` and `&gt;` or would they remain as they are like in a contenteditable div?

Answer (score 0):

User input is just raw text attached to a property in the DOM.

It isn't HTML, PHP, or anything else until something is done with it (such as a form being submitted or JavaScript reading the property and manipulating it).

Comment: Thanks though once the data inputted is manipulated through PHP, would the PHP code be affected by what was entered into the input field?

Comment: @Osman — It you are asking if the code will be evaluated as PHP code by the act of submitting a form to a PHP script: No, you have to write code to do that. It will just be text otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The raw text will reside in the standard HTML input and the PHP code a users enters will not be executed.

However depending on what your code does with it (send it to a database or web service), an attacker may potentially be able to perform an attack if it is not sanitized correctly.

Therefore, you should always aim to sanitize user input, both at the client and server side level, especially if it fires off to a database.

Different frameworks will support Sanitization.  In PHP, you have access to the following [sanitization filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

For reference, you should also be aware of other attacks such as SQL injection/XSS.  I would recommend looking at the OWASP top 10 which outlines some common web attacks and discusses [PHP filters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_PHP_Filters).

I have created a very basic example of reflecting back user input here which could happen if the attacker manages to save malicious code in your database:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("test").value;
eval(text);
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" value="alert('I have access to you document cookies and could use a windows redirection here')" />
```